# How to order and read from a very large bigquery table line by line in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Here is a piece of code I use to read from large bigquery tables line by line in python:

```
client = bigquery.Client('YOUR_CLIENT_NAME'); 
conn = dbapi.connect(client);
cursor = conn.cursor();
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM MY_LARGE_TABLE ORDER BY COLUMN_A');
line = cursor.fetchone();
while line != None:
      print('Do something with line')
      line = cursor.fetchone();
```

And this works fine for some tables. However, it is showing the following error for very large tables:

```
google.cloud.bigquery.dbapi.exceptions.DatabaseError: 403 Response too large to return. Consider specifying a destination table in your job configuration. For more details, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors
```

Basically, I have a very large table, `MY_LARGE_TABLE`, on CGP. There is a column in that table, `COLUMN_A`. I need to iterate over the table (in python) and extract all records with the same `COLUMN_A` and do some analysis on those records, and repeat this for all unique `COLUMN_A` values. My plan was (see the above python script) to use `ORDER BY COLUMN_A` in my query so that the results returned by `cursor.execute()` are ordered and all records with the same `COLUMN_A` are next to each other, and I can iterate over the table using `fetchone()` and do the task in one pass.

Comment: The error message says: "Consider specifying a destination table in your job configuration. For more details, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors" - did you do that?

Comment: Thanks. I know how to do that on GCP, but not sure how to do it within python. I guess I need to do it in python? Also, isn't ```cursor.fetchone()``` suppose to read line by line?

Comment: There's an example in Google's documentation: [Paging through query results](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/paging-results#page_through_query_results)

Comment: It gives me the same error when ```query_job.result()```.

Comment: You also may want to control the overarching analysis variable in python, just to make things easier (i.e. extract all distinct values of COLUMN_A with one query and loop through those with a WHERE clause and run analysis)...just an idea.

Comment: Thanks. I did try to select unique values for COLUMN_A and iterate over them and each time did a “SELECT … WHERE”, but it was too slow.

Comment: Can you try specifying a destination table as suggested by the error message by passing a `google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig` object to `job_config` parameter of `execute()`? Your execute() should look like this: `curr.execute(query,job_config=QueryJobConfig(destination="your_project.your_dataset.your_dest_table"))`

Comment: See reference https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.dbapi.Cursor#google_cloud_bigquery_dbapi_Cursor_execute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As confirmed by @khemedi, providing a destination table as suggested by the error solves the issue. See code snippet on adding a destination table on execute.

```
curr.execute(query,job_config=QueryJobConfig(destination="your_project.your_dataset.your_dest_table"))
```